# how to pass data to the nested component in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular8

In a parent html, I have many components such as chart 1,2,3,4,5. Then whenever I changed the date, I want to send the selected date to all the components. The code below is the implementation of the parent child event emitter. But I am getting no value from this html file when I check `<kt-chart1>` component? 
Also, I want to know when I get the data so I can sort chart by date by executing functions.

**html**

```
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!--                            date range field                             -->
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
        <mat-form-field class="flex-container">
            <div [formGroup]="form">
                <input
                    matInput
                    placeholder="Choose a date"
                    [satDatepicker]="picker2"
                    formControlName="date"
                    (dateChange)="DateChanged($event)"
                />
            </div>
            <sat-datepicker #picker2 [rangeMode]="true"> </sat-datepicker>
            <sat-datepicker-toggle
                matSuffix
                [for]="picker2"
            ></sat-datepicker-toggle>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="col-xl-6 chartPadding">
        <h4 class="text-center">Cost Per Tonne</h4>
        <kt-chart1 (sendingDateEmitter)="receivedDate($event)"></kt-chart1>
        <kt-chart2 (sendingDateEmitter)="receivedDate($event)"></kt-chart2>
        <kt-chart3 (sendingDateEmitter)="receivedDate($event)"></kt-chart3>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
    @Output() sendDateEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();

    DateChanged($event) {
        this.sendDateEmitter.emit($event.value);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To each of the charts add

```js
@Input() date: Date;
```

And pass it to charts

```html
<kt-chart1 (sendingDateEmitter)="receivedDate($event)" [date]="form.get('date').value"></kt-chart1>
<kt-chart2 (sendingDateEmitter)="receivedDate($event)" [date]="form.get('date').value"></kt-chart2>
```

Make sure form is initialized before rendering, otherwise you might need to do something like `[date]="form.get('date')?.value"`

To detect date changes in chart use [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.date) {
    // Date has changed, do something with it.
  }
}
```

Comment: Then do I need to Output vaule with emitter? I want to do something with the data received. probably changing the date of the chart.  then how do I know if I am getting the value or not

Comment: I added how to detect date change in your chart

Comment: it's property biding and then I don't need a event emitter at all. Is that right? what is the use of the question mark in form.get?

Comment: Yes, it is binding so remove Emitter entirely. If template renders before form is initialized it will throw something like `cannot read property value of undefined` because `form.get('date')` will be undefined. Read more about [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just declare a variable and bind it to Child's input parameter. Something like this:

Parent Component:

```
parentDate: Date;

DateChanged($event) {
  this.parentDate = $event.value);
}
```

Parent Component html:

```
<kt-chart1 [childDate]="parentDate"></kt-chart1>
```

Child Component

```
@Input() childDate: Date;
```

Angular will automatically take care of all the event emitter and passing of data you are taking to do.